# How do you shorten a two-word folder name for use in a command in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to shorten a folder name for a batch file, but I keep getting the message that the system cannot find the path.  The problem folder name is Microsoft Games.  I know that there are other ways to do this, but a one-line batch file is what I want.
With one-word names I am able to use the first six letters, plus ~1, or ~2, if there are two names that start the same, so I am using  Micros~2. What am I doing wrong?

```
copy c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Micros~2\Freecell\*.*   C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Current\Freecell
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add quotes like

```
copy "c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft Games\Freecell*.*" C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Current\Freecell
```

It's the only reliable way to do it, because the appended ~1 ~2 etc can be different across different computers.